# Is it possible to generate proper Nyquist plots using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, control-theory

I am trying to generate Nyquist plots via Python 3, but the graphs that Python produces don't seem to be complete.

Here is the system to be implemented for the Nyquist plot;

[image]

Here is my code for the Nyquist plot;

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import control

%matplotlib

G = control.TransferFunction((500), (1, 14, 43, 30))

rlist, klist = control.nyquist(G)

plt.show()
```

And here is the graph I get;

[image]

But from the textbook I'm using, this is the plot that they have;

[image]

Is there a way to get Python to provide a plot which is closer the actual solution, or is this the best approximation possible with Python right now?

Comment: Your book is plotting something else. You are plotting the open loop response

Comment: But the figure shows that the diagram is in the GH-plane.

Comment: What are V1, V2 etc? This cannot be the nyquist plot of GH. Look at how many times it crosses the real axis.